# exc_bad_instruction error in Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object

I made an array of objects but I receive this nerve wracking error on initializing array.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class question{

var image = UIImage()
var q1: String = "a"
var q2: String = "b"
var q3: String = "c"
var q4: String = "d"
var q = ["a","b","c","d"]

static let shared = question()

}

let quest: [question] = []


func set(){

quest[0].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-05-15 at 4.14.27 PM.png")
quest[0].q[0] = "Mount"
quest[0].q[1] = "Sun"
quest[0].q[2] = "Ground"
quest[0].q[3] = "Tree"


quest[1].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-05-15 at 4.15.32 PM.png")
quest[1].q[0] = "cloud"
quest[1].q[1] = "lake"
quest[1].q[2] = "rain"
quest[1].q[3] = "snow"


}
```

this is my model file, not viewController file. The func "set()" executes in ViewController file in viewDidLoad's override. EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION happens just in first initializing quest[0].image but it I add // before it, error moves to next lines.

Comment: try changing `var image = UIImage()` to `var image: UIImage!`

Comment: It doesn't change anything, beside if I forget about image and do this just for strings, this will happen again.

Comment: change `let quest` to `var quest`

Comment: Where are you loading the elements in to the `quest` array? Your code now has an empty `quest` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your set function like so :

```
func set(){

var tempQuest1 = question()
quest.append(tempQuest1)

var tempQuest2 = question()
quest.append(tempQuest2)

quest[0].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-05-15 at 4.14.27 PM.png")
quest[0].q[0] = "Mount"
quest[0].q[1] = "Sun"
quest[0].q[2] = "Ground"
quest[0].q[3] = "Tree"

quest[1].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-05-15 at 4.15.32 PM.png")
quest[1].q[0] = "cloud"
quest[1].q[1] = "lake"
quest[1].q[2] = "rain"
quest[1].q[3] = "snow"


}
```

There are a few things you need to correct :
1) Rename your `question` class to `Question`, all class (any types) in swift should be in upper case.
2) What is the need to make `question` class a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

The array `quest` does not contain any elements, you cannot access it by `quest[0]`.

First, make quest array be changeable:

```
    var quest: [question] = []
```

Then add elements like:

```
    let question = question()

    question.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-05-15 at 4.14.27 PM.png")
    question.q[0] = "Mount"
    question.q[1] = "Sun"
    question.q[2] = "Ground"
    question.q[3] = "Tree"

    quest.append(question)
```

Comment: I want an array of object type "question".